# MySQL code to convert Excel datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, type-conversion

Excel's datetime values look like 42291.60493, which means MySQL sees them as strings and not as dates.
Is there a MySQL code that can convert them to MySQL datetime? (i.e. [like in MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850605/t-sql-to-convert-excel-date-serial-number-to-regular-date))

Comment: I think you imported data from csv not excel.

Comment: How are you getting the data from Excel to MySQL? Might be easier to do the conversion to a standard datetime format in your export, using Excel itself. It'll probably be easiest, and it'll definitely be right.

Comment: I use a Microsoft Query with parameters (like the date) within Excel. I can reformat the date within as Excel till my heart's delight, but that's just for display within Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 solutions:

1. Convert your dates within excel to a formatted date string that conforms to mysql's date and time format using text() function within excel.
2. Convert the number using calculation to date within mysql:

(the expression below may be simplified)

```
select date_add(date_add(date('1899-12-31'), interval floor(@datefromexcel) day), interval floor(86400*(@datefromexcel-floor(@datefromexcel))) second)
```

Comment: Great answer. If you need microseconds to round correctly, modify this to date_add(date_add(date('1899-12-31'), interval floor(@datefromexcel) day), interval floor(86400000000*(@datefromexcel-floor(@datefromexcel))) microsecond)

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores date times as the number of days since 1899-12-31.  Unix stores the number of seconds since 1970-01-01, but only non-negative values are allowed.

So, for a *date*, you can do

```
select date_add(date('1899-12-31'), interval $Exceldate day )
```

This doesn't work for fractional days.  But, for a unix date time, this would be nice:

```
select $ExcelDate*24*60*60 + unix_timstamp('1899-12-31')
```

But negative values are problematic.  So, this requires something like this:

```
select ($ExcelDate - datediff('1899-12-31', '1970-01-01')) * 24*60*60
```

That is, just count the number of seconds since the Unix cutoff date.  Note:  this assumes that the date is after 1970-01-01, because MySQL doesn't understand unix dates before the cutoff.

Comment: date_add() has a different syntax for mysql: date_add(date('1899-12-31'), interval $Exceldate day )

Comment: Plus there's an extra "(" in the last line. Alas, a little apology, I edited the OP to reflect I meant MySQL datetime, not Unix datetime. Can you edit the answer accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Excel date values represent the number of days from 1899-12-30.  The reason for the odd value is that Excel needed to be compatible with Lotus 1-2-3 when it was introduced.  Lotus 1-2-3 date difference calculations mistakenly assumed that 1900 was a leap year, adding an extra day.  Microsoft replicated the bug for compatibility. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year)

The calculation would be as @Shadow noted above using the correct value.

Comment: It's also helpful.