# How to convert datetime (SQL Server) into Excel datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, datetime, datetime-conversion

**The problem**: I would like to convert `datetime` of SQL Server into Excel datetime format.

Example 1: from `2018-08-23 15:32:32.000` to `43335,65`

Example 2: from `1985-03-26 10:35:42.000` to `31132,44`

What I have tried: inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13850777/1008588) answer, I tried this query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @MyDatetime, GETDATE())
```

which works if you want to convert a date (without the hours), but how to convert the time too?

In Excel, the time is saved in the decimal part of the number so I've tried to use

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1899/12/30 00:00:00.000', GETDATE())
```

but this results in an overflow error.

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @JuValencia I am using SQL 12.0.2000 (2014)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `CAST`:

```
select CAST(GETDATE() as float)+2
```

How Dates work in Excel:
https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/how-dates-work-in-excel/

Basically any date can be stored as number of days since 1/1/1900. And the time is fractional value which is equal to (number_of_seconds_since_midnight)*(1/(24*60*60))

Need to add 2 days as Excel and SQL count number of days from a different start date.

Hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Convert your `DATETIME` to a `FLOAT` and add 2

**Example**

```
Declare @D datetime = '2018-08-23 15:32:32.000'

Select cast(@D as float)+2
```

**Returns**

```
43335.6475925926
```

Comment: @user1443098 Just standing on the shoulders of giants.  Thanks for the grin  :)

Comment: @user1443098 Honestly, been down this path before.  The int portion of a date converted to a float are days, while the decimal portion is essentially the percent of a day

Comment: @user1443098 The fun part is you can convert a float to a datetime Select cast(43335.6475925926 as datetime)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just get the date from the Db and let Excel convert it.  That way, if  Excel ever changes its internal representation, your SQL code won't have to change

Comment: unfortunately I need that format in my SQL Server database and I can't just let Excel convert when I read/write it in a report.