# Convert Number to Date in Presto

Tags: date, epoch, presto

I have a column in my table with the numerical equivalent to date in excel:

```
 TABLEA
 Col1
43276
43252
43253
43254
```

How do I convert this to a date in Presto? I want my final result to look like this:

```
      Col1
2018-06-25
2018-06-01
2018-06-02
2018-06-03
```

I attempted doing this but it gave results to 1970:

```
select *, date(from_unixtime(cast(Col1 as bigint))) as Col1 from TABLEA;
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850605/convert-excel-date-serial-number-to-regular-date to understand what your numbers are supposed to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert Excel Date Serial Number to Regular Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850605/convert-excel-date-serial-number-to-regular-date)