# Oracle Sql convert FROM short date TO string or long date

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, date

I'm reading a column that's a short date that I need to convert to a long date or a string.
Excel can do this readily , but I can't find out how to do it with Oracles SQL

Examples of the DATETIME column:

```
41590.6753233101
41593.7843996875
41593.7844002199
41593.7844007638
```

I would like to convert this to a human readable date.
Hate to have to direct someone move the out put to excel if you want to see the date.

Comment: What's your expect result from you sample data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel stores dates as the number of days since January 1, 1900, so to convert an Excel date, you just add them.

```
with mydates as (select 41590.6753233101 as datetime from dual
    union select 41593.7843996875 from dual
    union select 41593.7844002199 from dual
    union select 41593.7844007638 from dual)
select datetime, DATE '1899-12-30' + datetime
from mydates;
```

Output:

```
41590.6753233101    11/12/2013 4:12:28 PM
41593.7843996875    11/15/2013 6:49:32 PM
41593.7844002199    11/15/2013 6:49:32 PM
41593.7844007638    11/15/2013 6:49:32 PM
```

Comment: I think we must add `'1899-12-30'` because Microsoft incorrectly assumes that 1990 is a Leap Year : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850605/convert-excel-date-serial-number-to-regular-date   and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year

Comment: Note that @kfinity has done a `alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss';` to get that format of day/time.