# Epplus c# wrong date format for Cell

Tags: c#, date, format, styles, epplus

I have a template in Excel in which some Cells are  formated to date.
My Problem is that the Excel Cell isn't correctly updated after my code is executed.

```
globalTemplateSheet.Cells[3, 13].Value = "01." + date.Month + "." + date.Year;
```

I read something about Style.Numberformat.Format but the Excel Range never gets updated

[Example for my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paO4u.jpg)

Cell L3 is correct, Cell M3 should be the same, but to get the same as L i have to use the button "Enter"
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYH9M.jpg)

How can i format this Cell with the right Date.

Answer (score 1):

```
ws.Cells[3,13].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
ws.Cells[3,13].Formula = "=DATE(2016,12,1)";
```

Credits go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832423/excel-date-format-using-epplus)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but your locale settings also are important.

First, set the cell `Value` to `DateTime`:

```
globalTemplateSheet.Cells[3, 13].Value = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
```

Second, the format in your provided screenshots:

```
globalTemplateSheet.Cells[3, 13].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mmm. yy";
```