# C# EPPlus date format generating warning

Tags: c#, epplus

I have date like **08/09/21 which is MM/dd/yy format**. when i am showing this date in excel by EPPlus then warning is showing.

this is sample code i used. many ways i tried but no luck. please have a look.

1)

```
ws.Cells[1 + 1].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName].ToString()).Date;
ws.Cells[1 + 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "m/d/yy";
```

Warning is generated for the above code.

2)

```
ws.Cells[1 + 1].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName].ToString()).Date;
ws.Cells[1 + 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
```

Warning is generated for the above code.

I tried four way but nothing worked. so i am confused and not able to understand where i made the mistake. please suggest something because i need to show date in excel like **08/09/21 which is MM/dd/yy format**

Thanks

### EDIT

```
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Value = DateTime.Parse(dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yy");
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yy";
```

dtGroup is datatable and date is coming from db table where date has been stored as string.

i tried the above code and it is still not working. here i am pasting a screen shot that may help you to understand the issue. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is the warning you are receiving?

Comment: Warning is : Cell contains date string represented with only 2 digits for the year.

Comment: Is that 1921 or 2021? You have no way to tell. This isn't nitpicking, Lloyd's crashed in January 2020 due to such bugs. Don't use such strings. Dates in Excel are strongly-typed values, not strings.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName].ToString())` that's a critical bug. If that column already contains a date, all you need to do is `((DateTime)dtGroup.Rows[r][c]).Date`. If it's a string you need to specify the actual format or culture, otherwise your code will produce bad data if that string doesn't match the **current thread's** `CultureInfo` settings. In a web app those may be controlled by the browser's preferred language

Comment: i am working with winform application from where excel will be generating. the year 2021 but i need to show 21. when i put direct value in excel like 08/09/21  and set format mm/dd/yy then no warning is coming but when i do the same from EPPlus then warning is getting generate. looking help & suggestion.

Comment: Is it the same warning for all 4 formats you tried?

Comment: I already answered that. What is the field type? And the warning  won't go away because you **simply can't say** whether that is a 2021 or 1921. None. You **assume* but that assumption is 200% wrong. Before COVID-19 turned everything off, that exact bug was the most important and hilarious news of 2020 in IT

Comment: @Rafalon yes getting same working for 4 different approaches.

Comment: What warning are you talking about anyway? A compiler warning? Resharper warning? Excel warning? You can't "fix" any compiler or analyzer warnings as long as you use ambiguous formats but you can turn them off for that specific line. BTW you should really simplify that line

Comment: That's weird, because #2 and #3 seemed to have 4 digits for the year. Also not really sure about Excel, but in c# `mm` is for minutes, and `MM` is for months, so you might want to check that too

Comment: As long as you store a `DateTime` there's no data lost.  And one of the default Excel date formats does use two-digit years. Which suggests the warning comes from an analyzer. What is the actual warning text?

Comment: @Rafalon Format strings are definitely different between Excel and C#. In #2 and #3 the format is 4-digit year, yes. My suspicion is that the data to convert (input) is a 2-digit year string.

Comment: @Fildor That's right, therefore what OP calls "a warning" is probably actually "an error", and occurs on the first line, rather than on the second line

Comment: @Rafalon I hope, OP can clarify that. Otherwise, we'll never know :D

Comment: @Fildor that would result in a compilation error, not some kind of "warning". It's quite likely the OP is confusing errors with warnings, but we don't even have the actual warning yet so we could Google it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos don't you mean a runtime error, rather than a compilation error? (if `dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName]` is indeed a wrongly formatted date string)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly. Maybe it is a compiler warning/error or exception ... confused as I am right now, it could be anything.

Comment: Please, post what the value and datatype of `dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName]` are. Also, edit the question to add the exact message you're receiving.

Comment: Hi i have added code again what i am trying & screen shot too. please have a look.

Comment: when manually adding this date 08/09/21 in excel and set format like mm/dd/yy then excel not showing any warning but when doing the same using EPPlus then getting the warning issue. please rectify me what code i should use. thanks

Comment: i follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832423/excel-date-format-using-epplus but still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a date cell, so don't pass a string value to it, instead, pass a DateTime and apply a format (which will affect the presentation only, not the data). If `dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName]` is a DateTime, you can do

```
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Value =((DateTime)dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName]).Date;
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yy";
```

If you have a string:

```
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Value = DateTime.Parse(myString).Date;
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yy";
```

Comment: Thanks. i will try and let you know.

Comment: still no luck `

ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Value = DateTime.Parse(dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName].ToString()).Date;
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yy";`

Comment: @BabuBhatt you're getting the same error?

Comment: yes getting same error. i used this code which suppose to work as you said `ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Value=DateTime.Parse(dtGroup.Rows[r][dtGroup.Columns[c].ColumnName].ToString()).Date;
ws.Cells[r + 6, groupstartcol].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yy";


`