# Convert to DateTime from excel using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

My date format is like dd/mm/yyyy. When i have tried to convert it to Datetime I get this error:

> System.FormatException: Le DateTime représenté par la chaîne n'est pas
>   pris en charge dans le calendrier
>   System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

English error:

> System.FormatException: The datetime represented by the string is not
>   supported in the System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar calendar.

And the error source is:

```
devises2.date_observation = DateTime.ParseExact(elements[0],
                                           "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What are the contents of `elements[0]` that cause the error?

Comment: string[] elements;

Comment: I mean what is the value of `elements[0]`?  What is the specific string that causes the error?

Comment: The exception saw that the string that you're trying convert is not valid. Your string is not in the format "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: If you are really with Excel DateTime, then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981655/how-to-represent-a-datetime-in-excel. In Short is a float and not a text.

Comment: thanks a lot !you have reason because my date format is like "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your title you mention Excel. If that is where that date value came from, try

```
devises2.date_observation = DateTime.FromOADate(elements[0]);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx)