# convert decimal serial number from excel to mysql correctly

Tags: mysql, excel, datetime, typeconverter

I have a column in Excel csv with values like this

> 42973.74257

I want to convert it to MySQL date time by using:

> DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', INTERVAL (42973.74257*60*60*24) second) as date

However, it would give me an incorrect result

> 2017-08-28 17:49:18.048000

while the correct result should be

> 8/26/2017  5:49:18 PM

It add 2 more days to the result. As I have around 1M rows so I would not know if all the results would be incorrect.

Do you guys have any better way to convert serial numbers from excel to mysql?

Thanks,

H

Comment: MySQL dates use YYYY-MM-DD format by default. You can format differently with the [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Comment: Why do you think the value is off by two days? When I try the MySQL query `select to_days('2017-08-28') - to_days('1900-01-01');` I get 42973.

Comment: It add 2 more days to the result. 8/26 and 8/28. So I am not sure if the query would produce incorrect results for the whole database

Comment: how about trying to convert it to the proper date/time format in Excel before saving to a csv?

Comment: I have like 1M rows so doing so in excel is a nightmare

Comment: Ah, I think I have found the issue: Excel datetime values count 1900-01-01 as the value 1, not 0. And Excel has a bug that it believes 1900 is a leap year. That accounts for the two days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981655/how-to-represent-a-datetime-in-excel

Comment: Ahh, I see. So I just need to subtract 2 days to find the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is wrong by two days.

One of those days is because it actually treats 1st of Jan 1900 as *1*, not 0 ([ref](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349)).

According to [this blog post](http://www.kirix.com/stratablog/excel-date-conversion-days-from-1900), it's off by another day because Excel incorrectly treats the year 1900 as a leap year for legacy compatibility reasons.

If you subtract 2 from the value before passing it into your formula, it should work.