# Converting a pandas datframe column to date type with a particular format of date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This question is different from all the available questions and answers available in stack overflow because I do not want to change my data type to string in order to obtain desired output.

I find it as a most confusing and not able to find proper solution of my problem.
I read an excel file which have one column as following-

```
Date
9/20/2017 7:27:30 PM
9/20/2017 7:27:30 PM
11/21/2018 8:28:30 AM
7/18/2019 9:30:08 PM
.
.
.
```

I am taking this data from excel sheet with the help of dataframe

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
```

Firstly I want to remove time from this column. I am doing it as -

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='ignore', format='%d/%b/%Y').dt.date
```

It produces following output and datatype as datetime.date

```
Date
20/9/2017 
20/9/2017 
21/11/2018 
18/7/2019 
.
.
.
```

But I want it as following type  without changing it into string.Because I want to store this data into another excel file and this column must behave as a date column if we apply filtering in my excel sheet.

```
Date
20/Sep/2017
20/Sep/2017
21/Nov/2018
18/Jul/2019
.
.
.
```

I can produce above output by

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%b/%Y'))
```

But again this date column will be changed into string.But I do not want it as string. I want it as datetime type excluding time values from each cell.
A possible solution after converting it from string to datetime is as following but it will again add time values in it-

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

After executing above two steps it will also include time as 12:00:00 AM or 00:00:00 AM along with date value.

Hope I am clear.
How to obtained the desired result with final column value as date type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

> But I want it as following type without changing it into string

No it is not possible, if want datetimes without times there is only pattern `YYYY-MM-DD` in python/pandas.

```
#datetimes with no times
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').dt.floor('d')
#python dates
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').dt.date
```

For all custom formats are datetimes converted to strings like:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%b/%Y')
```

Comment: Is there any supporting library available to do this task?

Comment: @VishavGupta - what is reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Because I want my final dataframe to store in another Excel file. In that Excel file If I am applying filter than it treats value as string not date. Basically I am using this for automation of excel files.So that excel file will generate automatically in user defined format of every column.

Comment: @VishavGupta - hmmm, so not working if write dates to excel? Maybe is necesary use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').dt.floor('d')` for datetimes with no times, not `dt.date` for dates

Comment: Yes.It is not working if we write this dataframe dates to excel.Excel is treating it like string values.Also tried df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').dt.floor('d') but not able to produce desired output

Comment: Can you please suggest some method?

Comment: @VishavGupta - hmmm, I think only way is set some custom format in excel, because in python impossible

Comment: @VishavGupta - Maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981655/how-to-represent-a-datetime-in-excel/981865)

Comment: Thanks for help.The code provided by you also contains time column.Is there any other library available for it?

Comment: @VishavGupta - No idea, but I guess in python not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date_format in the excelwriter

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_datetime.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        date_format='%d/%b/%Y')
df.to_excel(writer)
```

Comment: But where to specify column name of date in above code?

Comment: as i understand, when writing the data to excel it will use this format for all the columns that are of datetime type

Comment: Can you please suggest some other method?

Comment: xlsxwriter also includes time in it as 12:00:00 AM but I do not want it.Also not producing output in desired format

Comment: I think it is not possible in python and pandas.

Answer (score 0):

think i am bit late here, as a workaround
do not format the date column , let it be a regular df date column, save the excel workbook and then  open the excel again and using openpyxl module format that column range

```
    import openpyxl

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    sheet = workbook['Sheet1'] # get the active sheet

    #-- assuming that the column is M and data starts from M2
    last_line_end = 'M' + str(len(df)+1)

    for row in sheet['M2:' + last_line_end]:
         for cell in row:
             cell.number_format = "DD/MM/YY"

    workbook.save(file_name)  # save workbook
    workbook.close()
```